# When SpatialFilter does spatial relationship between base and candidate how it link if one out of many in FME

Tags: spatial-join, fme-form, fme-transformer

I would like to know how this mapping works when SpatialFilter does spatial relationship between bases and candidate. As per "Pass Criteria: Pass Against One Filter. Each address point only needs to fall inside one polygon – not all of them." Lets take consider example if I have base as Parcel shape file and candidate as building centroid. When I am applying SpatialFilter with pass criteria as "Pass Against One Filter" then map one building centroid to one parcel if match to one but if match to more than one like vertically overlapping parcel or stacked parcel. then how its link to one parcel out of those ?

Overlapping means like sandwich layer.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would just link to the first of the parcels in order. The reason is that this is a Filter transformer. It's trying to filter the data based on the spatial relationship. It's not really doing a join.

So does the point fall inside all of these parcels? Yes, it does. And here is the information from the first parcel it falls inside.

If you wanted to get a list of all of the polygons the point falls inside, then the SpatialRelator transformer is probably the one to use. Or you could use the PointOnAreaOverlayer instead. Both of those would give you the results as a List, which you could then process with a ListExploder, ListConcatenator, or something like that.

Comment: so in case centroid point fall inside parcels and that parcels is vertically overlapped ( stacked parcel ) means centroid related to multiple but due to SpatialJoin it mapped one of this. Not sure what logic they use to mapped any one of those.

Comment: as part of learning I would like to know how they map to one out of many if related to many.

Comment: It would be the first feature I think. So the first parcel feature read from the source data is likely to be the only that provides the attributes to the point, even if the point falls inside multiple parcels. You can control the order of the parcels using the Sorter transformer if it helps.

Comment: Means can change sorting before spatial filter used ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Is there any documentation link from Safe.com ?

Comment: Probably here is the best source: https://community.safe.com/s/documentation - but also do a community search for things like lists and Sorter and feature order.